# How can I resolve error 'ProtocolHandshake.createSession' while running Appium code on Android?

Tags: appium-android

I'm getting the below issue, while trying to run the appium code in eclipse using java. Can anyone pls help me to resolve it

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:274)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:89)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:101)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:113)
at InstallationApp.InstallingAppInEmulator.main(InstallingAppInEmulator.java:26)

I tried changing the local host and all within the code.